# Issue with Making mailing labels with CiviCRM and Wordpress

Tags: civimember

I have an issue with an organizations CiviCRM database. It is a c-operative so I'm looking for any help possible to help them out.

Basically when doing an advance search, There are a number of groups selected, trying to than pick the action 'mailing labels' it brings us to a page to select the labels. When pressing the make mailing labels, the next URL goes nowhere. Is the sever missing something for the next steps? Is civiCRM missing something on setup for this to work? I feel like we are missing some set up on the new server for this to work correctly, but I have no idea what the issue is.

I have attached 2 screenshots to help explain, we are running CiviCRM 5.6.0 along with the newest version of wordpress.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Aaron

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSTOF.png)
[image]